# PHP preg_split() pattern for splitting by sentence periods with exception of spliting by periods in floats/prices

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I would like to be able to preg_split content by periods after sentences i.e.

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit 3.14 amet, elit. Vivamus sed elit eu. Morbi pulvinar dignissim.**

should output (dots in floats shouldn't be split):

```
array(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit 3.14 amet, elit',
  'Vivamus sed elit eu',
  'Morbi pulvinar dignissim'
)
```

not

```
array(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit 3',
  '14 amet, elit',
  'Vivamus sed elit eu',
  'Morbi pulvinar dignissim'
)
```

any ideas how the preg_split pattern should looks like? cheers

Comment: So you only want to split if there's a space-character or the end of the string after the dot? And you probably want to drop empty results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one may work

```
$res = preg_split('/\.[^\d]/', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works on your example, but I'm not sure it'll always do the job, but hope you can use it: `"/\.[^$|\d]/"`

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to split in case there's a space or end of string after the dot:

```
$res = preg_split('~\.( |$)~', $str);
```

This can give you empty results, which you can drop by setting the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag.

```
$res = preg_split('~\.( |$)~', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See as well [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split).